# Regarding どういたしまして usage

Tags: set-phrases, greetings

Japanese textbooks teach us to reply どういたしまして。 when people say　ありがとうございます。So generally it means "You're welcome~"

But I read that a lot of people saying that when we say どういたしまして。 it somewhat looks "arrogant". It's like we position ourself higher than the one we help. So the proper common reply should be どうも。 If maybe we're indeed someone in a higher position like a boss helping a janitor, then どういたしまして might be proper.

Is the statement above true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どういたしまして is one of the politest phrases you can say in response to *Thank you*, and it never sounds arrogant to me. Whether you are a boss or you're saying this to your boss, it doesn't matter.

That said, どういたしまして is definitely lengthy even for native speakers, and this phrase is only sometimes heard even in formal and/or classy conversations. In casual settings, shorter expressions like うん, はい, いいえ, いえいえ are probably more common. いいえ (lit. "No") in this context roughly means "My pleasure and you don't need to thank me."

どうも is an almighty phrase which can mean *Hi*, *Bye*, *Sorry*, *Thanks* and *You're welcome* depending on the context, but this phrase may sound rude if you used it an inappropriate way. Before you understand how どうも is used in real formal situations, I'd suggest you stick to どういたしまして, 大丈夫です, 問題ありません, etc.

See this question for other possible expressions.

- [How do you respond to thanks given?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1951/5010)